# No partitions selected for incremental stats update

Tags: hive, impala

Getting a message `No partitions selected for incremental stats update` when I run `COMPUTE INCREMENTAL STATS <table_name>` without partition clause in the command. But the table is partitioned with some column.

As per the documentation [here](https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_compute_stats.html) `COMPUTE INCREMENTAL STATS [db_name.]table_name [PARTITION (partition_spec)]` PARTITION clause is optional.

then I don't understand why I'm getting an err that "No partitions selected". Is it mandatory or any different versions available ? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is correct `PARTITION clause is optional.` and this is correct behavior of `COMPUTE INCREMENTAL STATS`.
Incremental stats gather stats as usual but if it finds a new partition, it gather stats and show message that it found a new partition and gather stats for that.

When you run `COMPUTE INCREMENTAL STATS mytab` for the first time, it will gather all the stats of all partitions and you will see message like `Updated 4 partition(s) and 200 column(s).`.
When you run `COMPUTE INCREMENTAL STATS mytab` again (without adding new partition), it doesn't find any new partition to gather stats. So it will show this message `No partitions selected for incremental stats update.` and gather stats of existing data.